# Vue 3 + webpack 5: cannot load images

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5, webpack-file-loader

In a Vue 3 project with Webpack 5, I am struggling to show images in the project.

My component has a simple img tag:

`<template> <div> <img src="./assets/logo.png" /> </div> </template>`

and my project has a src/assets folder with this logo.png

I have added the in webpack a rule to use the file-loader:

`{ test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader', },`

when I open the browser, for some reason the src from the image has this strange chrome-extension before:

[image: chrome-extension before url]

`

I cannot find anything in the docs about this. I tried to change the loader to the url-loader but the problem is the same. If I move the image to an scss file and use as background, same happens.

Anyone has any idea?

Used several loaders

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i, 
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

and therefore you see the image emitted to `dist/images/[name].[ext]`

So your import should really just be:

```
import img from '/images/[name].[ext]'
```